# Rename pagespeed to page-speed

Tags: discussion, retag-request

There's [some talk on the Webmasters meta site](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/stackoverflow-and-webmasters-tags-match/590) about making tags in common with this site have a common spelling. One example cited is the `page-speed` tag on Webmasters, where the matching tag on StackOverflow is `pagespeed`.

Should the `pagespeed` tag on StackOverflow be renamed to follow the tag-name norms, and as a bonus match the other site?

Comment: Is the "pagespeed" tag about the general concept of "how fast my page loads", or is it related to [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/)? Questions seem to be split between the two (though I supposed the second is basically a subset of the first).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it would be a good idea to rename `pagespeed` on Stack Overflow to `page-speed`.  It is more in line with the common taxonomy used, and it will make migrations smoother.

We should create a new tag, `google-pagespeed` for that tool.